# How should I fix a thrumming fan? Issue relates to fan housing

Tags: ceiling-fan, noise-reduction

I have a 3 year old Hunter-brand ceiling fan in my master bedroom. There is a thrumming sound (best described as a rhythmic buzz that happens with the same frequency of the blades).

I have ascertained the following:

1. The thrumming stops when the fan is turned off (so the blades don't need balancing);
2. All screws are tight;
3. ***The thrumming stops when the fan is on, but I push the ceiling fan up out of the downrod housing.***

That makes me think that the issue is to do with how the downrod ball is sitting in the housing. Somehow, the vibration of the engine is causing noise there.

Is there a way to fix this issue? Should I just get a new fan?

Thank you!

Comment: To me, your steps are describing that the blades are not balanced.  Your conclusion at Step-1 is incorrect.